# Cannot get camera list by android NDK(camera2 api)

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-camera2

Trying to build an app with Qt5.12.3 and android ndk, but cannot get camera list by "ACameraManager_getCameraIdList".

- Mobile : Sony xperia XA1 Ultra
- Qt: 5.12.3
- NDK : r19c
- minimum target: 24
- maximum target: 28
- Android library link to : libcamera2ndk.so and libmediandk.so, I link to the libs of api 28, not 24(android-28\arch-arm\usr\lib)
- permissions: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/
- arch : armeabi-v7a
- jdk : jdk1.8.0_201
- link of the adb logcat : put at [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KkQEKzsviVHLAlzDFFiI_EGZGW7Jmlr5) since it is long, You can find the crash point by the keywords "can get camera ids:"

Extra so files I add into the project

```
contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
        C:/Users/yyyy/programs/Qt/android_camera/../../../3rdLibs/Android/android-ndk-r19c-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r19c/platforms/android-28/arch-arm/usr/lib/libcamera2ndk.so
}
```

Source codes:

```
#include "mainwindow.hpp"
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDebug>

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID

#include <android/log.h>

#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QtAndroid>
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

void myMessageHandler(
        QtMsgType type,
        const QMessageLogContext& context,
        const QString& msg
        )
{
    const char*const applicationName="android_camera";

    QString report=msg;
    if (context.file && !QString(context.file).isEmpty()) {
        report+=" in file ";
        report+=QString(context.file);
        report+=" line ";
        report+=QString::number(context.line);
    }
    if (context.function && !QString(context.function).isEmpty()) {
        report+=+" function ";
        report+=QString(context.function);
    }
    const char*const local=report.toLocal8Bit().constData();
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,applicationName,local);
        break;
    case QtInfoMsg:
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,applicationName,local);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,applicationName,local);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,applicationName,local);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,applicationName,local);
        abort();
    }
}

void open_android_camera()
{
    auto result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.CAMERA"));
    if(result == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied){
        QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash =
                QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(QStringList({"android.permission.CAMERA"}));
        if(resultHash["android.permission.CAMERA"] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied){
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"permission deny";
        }else{
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"permission granted";
        }
    }

    qInfo()<<__func__<<"create camera manager";
    ACameraManager *camera_manager_ = ACameraManager_create();
    if(camera_manager_){
        qInfo()<<__func__<<"get camera ids";
        ACameraIdList *camera_ids = nullptr;
        auto const status = ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(camera_manager_, &camera_ids);
        qInfo()<<__func__<<"can get camera ids:"<<(camera_ids != nullptr)<<", status:"<<status;
        switch(status){
        case ACAMERA_OK:
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"ACAMERA_OK";
            break;
        case ACAMERA_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"ACAMERA_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER";
            break;
        case ACAMERA_ERROR_CAMERA_DISCONNECTED:
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"ACAMERA_ERROR_CAMERA_DISCONNECTED";
            break;
        case ACAMERA_ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY:
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"ACAMERA_ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY";
            break;
        default:
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"unknown status codes:"<<status;
        }
        if(camera_ids){
            qInfo()<<__func__<<"camera number:"<<camera_ids->numCameras;
        }
    }else{
        qInfo()<<__func__<<"cannot create camera manager";
    }
}

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);
    open_android_camera();
#endif

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Error code returned by ACameraManager_getCameraIdList is -866653748, none of the value of NdkCameraError.h looks like that, weird

Edit : looks like mobile of sony do not support camera api 2. Please check this link if you were [interested](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-xz1/themes/google-camera-mods-doesnt-xperia-xz1-t3953247).

Comment: `ACameraManager_getCameraIdList` returns a status code. What is the returned value?

Comment: returned value is "-870323804", don't know this map to which state, will post it later

Comment: @Michael Check the header file NdkCameraError.h, cannot find error codes like "-870323804", this is weird

Comment: [ACameraManager_getCameraIdList](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera.html#acameramanager_getcameraidlist) can return 4 possible status code, please put a switch case there and figure out what the status code is.

Comment: @frogatto Checked with the four status code, none of them equal to "-870323804"

Comment: One thing that immediately jumps out to me is that you are completely ignoring the Android activity lifecycle. The example at https://github.com/sixo/native-camera/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/sisik/cam/MainActivity.kt only initializes the camera in the `onResume` callback (ie when the application is on the foreground). Have you tried delaying the camera access to whatever Qt's equivalent is of the `onResume` callback?

Comment: @Botje When using Qt we don't care about the Activity usually(we don't write the codes by any lines of platform specific codes unless it is inevitable), thanks for the points, maybe I can't init the camera directly from c++

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include _full_ logcat from running your app, including every process, not just your own app.  That may contain errors/logs from the camera service that could help track down the issue.

Comment: @EddyTalvala Updated, this logcat is generated by "adb logcat > logcat.txt", please tell me if I do it wrong or you need more info, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the full log - unfortunately nothing in the log is informative, which is surprising and sad.

Comment: @Eddy Talvala Thanks for your helps, maybe this is a problem of sony, you can check this link--https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-xz1/themes/google-camera-mods-doesnt-xperia-xz1-t3953247. I am surprise this could happen since sony is a big player of mobile camera