# Access camera frame of android without drawing them and send them back to c++

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-camera2

I would like to access the camera frames of Android mobile, process them and draw the results by the Qt5,  have tried with the Android ndk but it fail(post at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246410/cannot-get-camera-list-by-android-ndk#59246410)). All of the examples I found teach us how to use the Intent to use the camera app, or draw the camera frame on some sort of Surface, could I access the camera frames without drawing them? All I need is reading the frames of the camera continuous and send the camera buffer to c++. Thanks

Edit : Is it possible to make this work by JNI(use java api to access the frame, passed the buffer back to c++ without drawing the preview by java)?

Comment: I found https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/ndk/camera in just five minutes of googling.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, I studied this post and use the android ndk to do the job, but it do not work, you can check the old post I posted

Comment: So why did you ask this question then? You knew how to do it but you got an error when implementing it. Did you try compiling the sample project linked there? Did _that_ work? If not, why not?

Comment: Your post does not mention at all that you were following that article, nor does it contain an [mcve]. You should try to actually debug that issue before changing technologies completely.

Comment: @Botje The codes I post are very close to the minimal reproducible example, If you have developed on android by Qt5. If you cannot understand my codes, please ask, I am happy to help

Comment: And I answered there. As for this question: Yes, it is possible but it will be painful and slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204042/discussion-between-stereomatching-and-botje).